# Html5 Audio play weird delay

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Im having trouble locating the problem with a simpletimer with intervals i created. ([timer.michellmorso.com](http://timer.michellmorso.com))

The timer i set to play a sound for every second the last 3 seconds. When i set the timer to 10 seconds the sound plays as it should, but when i set the timer to 12 seconds the first play of the sound has a delay and plays almost at the same time as the sound on the 2 second??

Im at a loss here brothers, i would really appreciate some help figuring this out. thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300" rel="stylesheet">

<style type="text/css">
 html, body {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  user-select: none;
 }

 input {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 300;
  font-kerning: 100;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: none;
  border: 0px;
 }

 #timer {
  font-size: 520px;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 100;
  height: 520px;
  line-height: 520px;
  text-align: center;
 }

 #rounds {
  width: 275px;
  float: left;
 }

  #rounds input {
   width: 100px;
   text-align: right;
  }

 button {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 100;
  font-kerning: 100;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
 }

 span {
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome, Opera, Safari */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none; /* Standard syntax */
 }

 #supp {
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 70px;
 }

 input:focus,
 select:focus,
 textarea:focus,
 button:focus {
  outline: none;
 }

 }
</style>

<body onload="init()">
 <img src="r_logo.jpg" width="300">
 <input type="text" name="timer" id="timer" value="1:00" placeholder="0:00">
 <p>
  <div id="supp">
   <div id="rounds">
    <span>Rounds:</span>
    <input type="text" id="roundsNum" name="rounds" value="10" placeholder="0">
   </div>
 </p>
 <button id="btn" onclick="startTimer()">START</button>
 </div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var timer;
 var t;
 var display;
 var tIn;
 var tRn;
 var sec;
 var min;
 var rounds;
 var round = 1;
 var running = false;
 var beep;
 var roundBeep;
 var endBeep;

 function init() {
  beep = new Audio("beep.mp3");
  beep.preload = 'auto';
  roundBeep = new Audio("round.mp3");
  roundBeep.preload = 'auto';
  endBeep = new Audio("end.mp3");
  endBeep.preload = 'auto';
 }

 function p(sound, vol = 1) {
  console.log("PLAYING SOUND!:" + sound);
  sound.volume = vol;
  sound.play();
 }

 function startTimer() {
  if (running == true) {
   stopTimer();
   return;
  }
  running = true;
  document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = "STOP";
  tIn = document.getElementById("timer").value;
  tRn = document.getElementById("roundsNum").value;
  rounds = tRn;
  round = 1;
  resetTime();
  document.getElementById("timer").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("roundsNum").disabled = true;
  timer = setInterval(eSec, 1000);
 }

 function stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  p(endBeep);
  console.log("TIMER STOPPED");
  running = false;
  document.getElementById("timer").value = tIn;
  document.getElementById("roundsNum").value = tRn;
  document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = "START";
  document.getElementById("timer").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("roundsNum").disabled = false;
 }

 function resetTime() {
  t = tIn.split(":");
  min = t[1] != undefined ? t[0] : 0;
  sec = t[1] ? t[1] : t[0];
 }

 function eSec() {

  if (sec == 0 && min > 0) {
   min -= 1;
   sec = 59;
  } else if (min == 0 && sec == 0 && rounds == round) {

   stopTimer();
   console.log("TIMER ENDED");
   return;

  } else if (min == 0 && sec == 1 && rounds != round) {

   round++;
   p(roundBeep);
   resetTime();
   console.log("ROUND");

  } else {
   sec -= 1;
   if (sec < 4 && sec != 0) {
    p(beep);
    console.log("beep");
   }
  }
  document.getElementById("roundsNum").value = round + "/" + rounds;
  document.getElementById("timer").value = min > 0 ? min + ":" + sec : sec;
 }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I am really tried, but I did not catch the delay. Is it happens in all browsers?

Comment: good, I think I fixed it! :) removed the play sounds in the init() function. updated the code above. thanks!